# jQuery hide() Randomly Showing Last Div

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have been banging my head and racking my brain. I am using the jQuery hide(), show() on fade and all appears to work properly for sorting/filtering. Yet the last div (container) (Warranties) randomly keeps popping back up when I am making my selections from the drop down when it's supposed to be hidden. I have a function that checks for a class to see if its attached - titleShow. I've traced out through everything, used my console.log and even if it doesn't have the class, "titleShow" it still pops up. Not sure what I am missing, but wanting a fresh pair of eyes to help me find the root cause of my problem. Thanks in advance! Hopefully it's something minor and not a bug!

Page: http://www.collegepark.bfmdev1.com/practitioners/literature

JavaScript

```
var titlesToShow = [];
    var wordsSelected = [];


     /* drop down functions for basic filtering */
    jQuery("#foot-filter").change(function () {
        sortPDFs($(this).val());
    })

    jQuery("#category-filter").change(function() {
        sortPDFs($(this).val());
    });

    /* checking each list item for the word selected */
    function sortPDFs(wordSelected) {

        titlesToShow = [];

        wordsSelected.push(wordSelected);

        if(wordsSelected.length>2) {
            wordsSelected.shift();
        };

        $(".lit-pdfs li").each(function() {

            var $li = $(this);

            if($li.hasClass('displayItem')) {
                $li.removeClass('displayItem');
            }
            for(var i=0; i<wordsSelected.length; i++) {
                if ($li.data("document-type").indexOf(wordsSelected[i]) > -1) {
                    $li.addClass('displayItem');
                    $li.fadeIn(300, function(){ 
                        $li.show(); 
                    });
                    checkForTitle($li.parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id'));
                } else {
                    if(!$li.hasClass('displayItem')) {
                        $li.fadeOut(300, function(){ 
                            $li.hide(); 
                        });
                    }

                }
            };
        });

        showHideContainers(titlesToShow);
    };
    /* adds the id of the .lit-container to be added to ensure it shows */
    function checkForTitle(addTitle) {

        if(titlesToShow.length==0) {
            titlesToShow.push(addTitle);
        } else {
            var found = titlesToShow.indexOf(addTitle);

            if(found == -1) {
                titlesToShow.push(addTitle);
            };
        };
    };
    /* hides and shows the proper title bars (pdf containers) */
    function showHideContainers(titlesToShow) {
        $(".lit-container").each(function() {

            $pdfContainer = $(this);
            $pdfContainer.removeClass('titleShow');

            for(var i = 0; i<titlesToShow.length; i++) {
                if($pdfContainer.attr('id') == titlesToShow[i]) {
                    $pdfContainer.fadeIn(300, function(){ 
                        $pdfContainer.show(); 
                    });
                    $pdfContainer.addClass('titleShow');
                }
            };
            if(!$pdfContainer.hasClass('titleShow')) {
                $pdfContainer.fadeOut(300, function(){ 
                    $pdfContainer.hide(); 
                });
            };
        });
    };
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the fade code and hide/show instantly?  You appear to be adding/removing a class to determine if the items should be shown/hidden, this this add/remove does not coincide exactly with showing/hiding - so you add class, start to show, before show finished, remove class etc.  ie race conditions.  Use `:hidden` `:animated` and/or `:visible` rather than control this outside jquery.

Comment: You know what, removing the fadeIn and fadeOut on the containers after sorting through the PDFs worked. Thanks for the help! it's not as "fadey" if that's even a word....but it works. :) Thank you!.

Comment: I suspected that might be the issue.  Hard to code state-based event handlers with async animations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is only about the Warranties category.

I think you should first code your page so that no item is shown at page load. If it is not possible, then you should show all the items.

Then I would say, you need two different functions to sort for a product and sort for a category.

This way, if the user selects a category and / or a product, it would work.

Also, you could use the jQuery's toggle function to display/hide items. The code would be clearer.

Try to make it simple.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. The functionality works like its supposed to except for that last warranty title. It sorts and filters as its supposed to by hiding the specific pdfs (which works perfectly), and if a PDF is visible, it adds the container div ID to an array...I used data types on each li element and filtered that way. Code is pretty clear and straightforward. I am using 2 functions.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle with few products and few categories and I help till its done, unless you have already found a solution.